# What does fp.read((char*)&cont,sizeof(contact)) do in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, while-loop, char, sizeof

i don't understand this part of an random code!

```
  while(fp.read((char*)&cont,sizeof(contact)))
        {
            if(cont.getPhone()!=num)
            {
                fp2.write((char*)&cont,sizeof(contact));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you read [`std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)?

Comment: What is `fp`, `cont`, `fp2`, and `contact`?

Comment: please include a [mcve].

Comment: Depending on the definition of `contact`, it either reads data into a contact object, or it creates undefined behavior.

Comment: "While you can read a thing from this place, if that thing's phone number is different from 'num', write it to this other place."

Comment: If `contact` is not a POD type this is undefined behavior. Use caution if you use this method with your own classes.